# Detect Chromium browsers except for Brave - JS not working

Tags: javascript, user-agent, brave

I am trying to detect whether the browser is Brave, something else based on Chromium, or something not based on Chromium. However, the below HTML with the Javascript just shows up empty:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") == -1) {
  document.write("<p>not Chromium</p>");
} else {
  if (navigator.brave && await navigator.brave.isBrave() || false) {
    document.write("<p>Brave</p>");
  } else {
    document.write("<p>Chromium, but not Brave</p>");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This just returns an empty page. Edge complains about `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'navigator'` in line 9, Firefox complains about `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after condition` line 9:31.

I took the Brave detection bit that seems to be the source of the problem from here: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/brave-user-agent-detection.html

Comment: You can't use `await` outside an async function.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to replace it with `if (!!navigator.brave)` and it seems to work for now. Firefox, Edge and Brave return three different outputs.

Comment: There's no need for `!!`, just `if (navigator.brave)` is equivalent.